# Mongo connector [Mongodb - Elastic Search] Docker Crashes

Tags: mongodb, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml, also i have enabled rs.initiate(config) for replica set. What am I doing wrong here? How to connect replica set. And how to know primary of replica set to initiate mongo-connector. I see `Member techiez_db_container_1:27017 is now in state PRIMARY` log after the crash. How to synchronise or wait for mongo_one container to become primary.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  mongo_one:
    container_name: techiez_db_container_1
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --replSet techiez-set
    ports: ['27017:27017']
    networks: ['techiez']

  mongo_two:
    container_name: techiez_db_container_2
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --replSet techiez-set
    ports: ['27018:27017']
    networks: ['techiez']

  mongo_three:
    container_name: techiez_db_container_3
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --replSet techiez-set
    ports: ['27019:27017']
    networks: ['techiez']

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.16
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports: ['9200:9200']
    networks: [techiez]

  mongoconnector:
    image: yeasy/mongo-connector
    links: ['elasticsearch:elasticsearch', 'mongo_one:mongo']
    depends_on: ['mongo_one', 'mongo_two', 'mongo_three', 'elasticsearch']
    networks: [techiez]

networks:
  techiez: {}
```

Below is the Crash Log

```
mongoconnector_1  | Logging to mongo-connector.log.
mongoconnector_1  | Exception in thread Thread-1:
mongoconnector_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 425, in __init__
mongoconnector_1  |     self._ensure_connected(True)
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1083, in _ensure_connected
mongoconnector_1  |     self.__ensure_member()
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 957, in __ensure_member
mongoconnector_1  |     member, nodes = self.__find_node()
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1048, in __find_node
mongoconnector_1  |     raise AutoReconnect(', '.join(errors))
mongoconnector_1  | pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: mongo:27017 is not primary or master
mongoconnector_1  | 
mongoconnector_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
mongoconnector_1  | 
mongoconnector_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
mongoconnector_1  |     self.run()
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
mongoconnector_1  |     func(*args, **kwargs)
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 285, in run
mongoconnector_1  |     tz_aware=self.tz_aware, **self.ssl_kwargs)
mongoconnector_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 428, in __init__
mongoconnector_1  |     raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
mongoconnector_1  | pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: mongo:27017 is not primary or master
mongoconnector_1  | 
techiez_mongoconnector_1 exited with code 0
```